# Is there a way to tell when a react component has been seen?

Tags: react-native, view

Is there a way to tell if a react component (like a view/TouchableOpacity in a list) has been seen?

Comment: Depends how you define "seen". Whether it's been in the viewport? Whether someone looked at it?

Comment: Like for a list, if it has appeared on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

Might help if you check View's props. [removeClippedSubviews](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view#removeclippedsubviews) seems to meet your request

Comment: How exactly does this tell if a view has been seen or not?

Answer (score 0):

Set a bool flag in your state. When the component renders, have it trigger a function to set that flag to true.

Comment: No like in a scroll view. Different items. i wanted to know if they have been scrolled on /viewed